# Best app structure for my needs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am designing an app with Android 6.0 and Android Studio. I think a good start for my app is the NavigationDrawer template which comes with the AndroidStudio. 
Keep in mind the Gmail app. It has a NavigationDrawer. You click and it displays a list of messages. Then when you click a message it navigates to another activity/fragment  showing all the details of it( action bar also changes with different options, it allows you to navigate back with the back arrow, etc ).

So my app has a Navigation drawer. For each option on it, when clicked, it populates the container fragment of the main Activity with a Recyclerview and Cards view. So far so good.
Next what I want is to click one of this cards and open an activity/fragment to perform actions over this card like modify its content, erase etc. 
Now the problem I have is that I don’t know if I amb designing my app structure well. Should I work with fragments or should I work with activities when I click navigationdrawer options? I want to follow the design of Gmail app.
I tried to launch activities when I click a cardview but then I lose the possibility of going back using the back arrow on the action bar.
If I launch a fragment instead of an activity, I don’t have the possibility to go back either.
The floatingActionButton is another problema because it is displayed with the NavigationDrawer template. As you know it is floating on MainActivity so If I work with fragments and I want to use it I need to change its functionality depending on what fragment is displayed. Do you guys it is a good solutions ori t is better to launch a new activity with its own floating action button?  Is it better to create a floating action button inside each activity or just reuse the one that it is created with the initial template?

Long story short, how do you guys do this kind of navigation? Could you post a little example?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i recommend to use separate activities for launching clicked items.
Fragments are meant to be used as a sub-part of activity & not as a separate screen.
Although, technically possible to design app flow with just one activity & multiple pages/screens as fragments; one should not go that way as it requires you to maintain navigation sequence rather manually for up/back type navigation.
So, reply on standard android convention to use activities for logically separate screens & use fragments only to create sub-screens e.g. to create multiple account details fragments (when select let us say personal banking option) which can swapped with view pager like concepts.